# stackexchange.com homepage really needs a responsive design

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, stackexchange.com, responsive-design

If you hear about Stack Exchange from a random person, and you’re thinking

> Oh I want to go check out this nifty site kids these days like

you probably will open up your phone’s browser and look up `stack exchange`. However, the top link is, logically, to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com). No problem here, right?

Wrong. On my iPhone 7, this is what it looks like:

[image: it is very small and non-responsive]

This is the first page a user will see if they look up Stack Exchange. **While it’s a different question how well the homepage works on desktop, it’s a very bad first impression on mobile, especially compared to the lovely responsive design seen on the most frequently viewed pages.**

**This page is desperately asking for a responsive design, or at least a mobile version.**

Comment: I rarely get these buttons in the corner right, when on the phone.

Comment: @ankii what do you mean? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I mean that I cannot tap  on them when on the site in full mode. So I second your FR about it being responsive.

Comment: The profile page could also use responsive design. Same with the review queues.

Comment: Come on, SE. This is the main reason I held onto Android application for so long and still would if I could. Lack of mobile version of *literal main page of SE* is unacceptable.

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica se.com is second class citizen of SE, it does not get lots of attention, if it all, from the developers, because it's 1) hard to maintain and has its own codebase, and 2) It's historical hybrid which was never defined very well. My assumption is that they will totally re-design it, and change the contents, at some point.