# Can the main HNQ page be made more mobile aware?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, hot-questions

The mobile aware functionality of Stack Exchange has steadily improved over the years and it’s mainly a joy to use.

However, when my fat thumbs stumble onto the main HNQ landing page (stackexchange.com), I’m presented with the desktop version of the site which forces me to squint and pinch my way through the navigation path to find something useable on my phone.

Is there a plan to make HNQ more mobile-friendly (or at least easier to get out of)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stackexchange.com homepage really needs a responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335961/stackexchange-com-homepage-really-needs-a-responsive-design)

Comment: Sadly no, because there was no answer to that question.

Comment: You may be unaware of this change since you left the network, but the automatic text for duplicate questions has changed from "Possible duplicate of" to "Does this answer your question?".

Comment: Also, the fact that the system continues to use this same default text even when choosing an unanswered target is [something that I've brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340009/new-duplicate-automatic-comment-makes-literally-zero-sense-when-voting-to-close).

Comment: That makes sense. In a sort of nonsensical way. Thank you. Something else to just shrug and put up with I guess.

Comment: Is it really mobile aware? Isn't it "just" [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Yes, I had forgotten the term, and the HNQ page isn't responsive.