# No padding after 'Log in' link at the top of the Stack Exchange home page

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

On both Safari and Firefox (I haven't tried other browsers), the `Log in` link at the top right corner comes all the way up to the edge of the browser window.  After looking over the recent questions here on Meta, I didn't see that anyone has reported this issue yet, so here is a screenshot showing its appearance on both browsers:

[image: image of possible text alignment bug]

This seems like it probably isn't an intentional design choice, so I'd guess it's a bug.  Resizing the browser window doesn't fix it.

Comment: That's because stackexchange.com isn't responsive yet. There is some fixed width of 1380px somewhere, when the screen is bigger than that, all is good. It just does not adjust itself to smaller screens. (Or mobile of course.)

Comment: Related request: [stackexchange.com homepage really needs a responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335961/stackexchange-com-homepage-really-needs-a-responsive-design)