# Can we have the SE site's clicked icon enlarge but zoom upward, and put the open button at top?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, stackexchange.com

When I start SE at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid, the sites are tiles to be clicked on. When I click on a tile, it enlarges, then zooms down so it lines up with the row below, and the open button is now below the screen of my laptop, so I need to scroll down to click.

Can we have the icon enlarge but zoom upward, and put the open button at top? Then it would stay in range of the laptop screen, ready to click.

Comment: To be honest I don't think that this is something that the company would even start to consider doing. That website is pretty old and they are more likely to overhaul it completely.

Comment: To be clear: [the Stack Exchange homepage hasn't been redesigned to be more responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335961/241919).

Comment: Well it's part of making se.com responsive, which doesn't appear to be anywhere on SE roadmap, sadly. e.g. the [most popular related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335961/stackexchange-com-homepage-really-needs-a-responsive-design) doesn't even have [tag:status-review] yet, or any official comment.

Comment: It's merely a list of sites. How hard can it be to make it responsive, ha ha?